# Intersection between two shell lists without temp files

Tags: list, shell, intersection

Lots of questions has been put on the web about the result that I want.
Imagine, you have got two lists in a shell script:

```
 LIST_ONE="key1 key2 key3 key4"
 LIST_TWO="key2 key3 key5"
```

I would like the intersection of this two lists:

```
 LIST_FIN="key2 key3"
```

I found some things to do like using `comm` command. But it always uses files, and I **can't** use temp files.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use process substitution:

```
grep -o -f <(echo "$LIST_TWO" | tr ' ' '\n') <<< "$LIST_ONE" | xargs
key2 key3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$ LIST_ONE="key1 key2 key3 key4"
$ LIST_TWO="key2 key3 key5"
$ comm -12 <(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${LIST_ONE}" | sort) <(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${LIST_TWO}" | sort)
key2
key3
$
```